# Custom Task Pane, PowerPoint 2010 and slides pane

Tags: .net, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint, customtaskpane

I have a refresh issue in PowerPoint 2010, with the slides preview pane (*left pane in the normal view*).

To better isolate my issue, I created a Ppt 2010 Addin with VS 2010.
The addin adds a custom task pane with a user control containing a single button with this code in its click callback: `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).MoveTo(2)`

I you click this button on a presentation with 3 slides and page numbers in the footers, the thumbnails in the slides pane
are greyed and do not refresh until you click in the pane.

This does not happen if:

1. The same code is called from a ribbon button
2. The code is called by a vba macro
3. There is no slide numbers on the slides

This is a very specific issue, but really anoying if you work a lot with custom task pane.
Basically, if the code you execute from a custom task pane moves slides, you loose the refresh of the thumbnails in the slides pane.

Any idea for a simple workaround?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?